# Find and compare duplicate values in an excel column, compare matching sums and print smallest (excluding blanks)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel problem need help with. I have two columns in excel like below, one with numeric values and the second with some sort of option IDs. I am trying to compare the sum of the matching options and print the smallest value and option ID. So formulas should print 3 and O1 in the below case. The complexity I have here is that I don't know how many options eventually there will be. So I can't do it by factoring all the option IDs in a formula to compare and print results. Additionally, there are some other values in the ID column, such as x(not an option, should be excluded) and blank cells.

```
2 / O1 
4 / O2 
1 / O1 
1 / x
4 / O3 
2 / -
5 / O2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=LET(X,CHOOSE({1,2},SUMIFS(A1:A7,B1:B7,B1:B7),B1:B7),INDEX(SORT(FILTER(X,LEFT(INDEX(X,,2))="O")),1))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @JvdV, I have used your formula with the same test data, but I get a REF error. would you know the reason for that? is there anything I need to additionally define before using the formula?

Comment: @ElvinIbishli, the formula should work if you have Excel ms365. Maybe you don't have the english version and you have to change `CHOOSE({1,2}` tot `CHOOSE({1\2}` ? You don't need anything else really.

Comment: JvdV could you please also let me know how I can print the option ID on D2 instead of E1, if not an issue :)

Comment: @ElvinIbishli, the easiest for you to perform would to wrap the above in `=TRANSPOSE()`.

Comment: @ElvinIbishli Sir, the one shared by JvdV Sir is short, then why did you accepted my answer, because sir's formula is better here

Comment: Thanks for checking on this Mayukh. I pretty much got the correct formula at the same time from both of you. Both works perfectly, so I clicked both as the correct answer and helps me with my problem. Did I do something wrong? :)

Comment: No Sir, you are all good, but @JvdV Sir's formula is better than mine, so you should use the one as sir has given.  I dont mind about upvotes or accept an answer, the best should be rewarded.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, you may ***try*** as shown below, formulas used applicable to **MS365** users only

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

---

• Formula used in cell `C1`

```
=LET(array,FILTER(A1:B7,ISNUMBER(B1:B7*1)*(B1:B7<>"")),
id,INDEX(array,,2),
u,UNIQUE(id),
sumf,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(x,SUMIFS(A1:A7,B1:B7,x))),
FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2},sumf,u),sumf=MIN(sumf)))
```

---

And when writing this formula if you have enabled the **Beta Channel** from **Office Insiders** then you can use the `HSTACK()` in place of `CHOOSE()`

[image]

• Formula used in cell `C1`

```
=LET(array,FILTER(A1:B7,ISNUMBER(B1:B7*1)*(B1:B7<>"")),
id,INDEX(array,,2),
u,UNIQUE(id),
sumf,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(x,SUMIFS(A1:A7,B1:B7,x))),
FILTER(HSTACK(sumf,u),sumf=MIN(sumf)))
```

---

Following **Excel functions** used to derive the **Output**,

- `LET()` -- Used to assigns names to calculation results,
- `FILTER()` -- Used twice, in the beginning to create an `array` of
  results which excludes the `non numeric` as well as the `blanks`, and
  at last to get the required output,
- `ISNUMBER()` -- Used within `FILTER()` to get numeric values, returns
  `TRUE`,
- `INDEX()` -- Used to extract the ID's from the `array`,
- `UNIQUE()` -- Used to get the unique values from the `id`,
- `BYROW()` & `LAMBDA()`-- Used to apply a `LAMBDA()` to each row and to
  return an array of the sum of unique values,
- `SUMIFS()` -- Used with in `LAMBDA()` to get the sum
- `CHOOSE()` / `HSTACK()` -- Used to return the array formed by
  appending each of the array arguments in a column-wise fashion,
- `MIN()` -- Used to return the min of sum values.

---

**EDIT**

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `B13`

```
=TRANSPOSE(LET(array,FILTER($A$1:B11,(LEFT(B1:B11)="O")*(B1:B11<>"")),
id,INDEX(array,,COLUMN(B1)),
u,UNIQUE(id),
sumf,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(x,SUMIFS($A$1:$A$11,B1:B11,x))),
FILTER(HSTACK(sumf,u),sumf=MIN(sumf))))
```

Or,

```
=TRANSPOSE(LET(array,FILTER($A$1:B11,(LEFT(B1:B11)="O")*(B1:B11<>"")),
id,INDEX(array,,COLUMN(B1)),
u,UNIQUE(id),
sumf,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(x,SUMIFS($A$1:$A$11,B1:B11,x))),
FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2},sumf,u),sumf=MIN(sumf))))
```

And now drag right for the rest!

Comment: Thanks, boss for taking your time to help out here. It seems to be working perfectly.

Comment: Great Sir, glad to know it worked in the required way